# Typescript type inference on dynamically accessed object properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

```
interface CustomResponse {
    data: string;
    status: number;
    [key: string]: string | number;
}

const RESPONSE_PROPS = {
  DATA: "data",
  STATUS: "status",
};

const response: CustomResponse = {
    data: "test",
    status: 200,
};

let dataWrong: string = response[RESPONSE_PROPS.DATA];
let dataRight: string = response.data;
```

`dataWrong` gets the error

```
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

In cases like above, how to get `dataWrong` infer right type in typescript? Is type assertion (better type guards) the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RESPONSE_PROPS.DATA` is typed as `string` if you use an `as const` assertion (which will make the compiler keep the string literal type `"data"` for `RESPONSE_PROPS.DATA`) it works as expected:

```
interface CustomResponse {
    data: string;
    status: number;
    // [key: string]: string | number; not necessary for the code to work
}

const RESPONSE_PROPS = {
    DATA: "data",
    STATUS: "status",
} as const;

const response: CustomResponse = {
    data: "test",
    status: 200,
};

let dataWrong: string = response[RESPONSE_PROPS.DATA];
let dataRight: string = response.data;
```

**Note:** If the string literal type is used to index you don't really need the index signature.

Comment: Wow this worked.. May I get some doc reference/article on this `const` type inference?

Comment: @Tamil https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html

Comment: another one https://blog.logrocket.com/const-assertions-are-the-killer-new-typescript-feature-b73451f35802/